# Apache Camel SQS component to async SEDA queue, SQS messages not acknowledged or deleted

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-sqs

Apache Camel 2.15.2

I have a route like this, the messages are sent to MyProcessor but are NOT deleted from SQS, they go invisible for 30 seconds, but then re-appear in SQS as available messages.

```
from("aws-sqs://myqueue?amazonSQSClient=#myclientbean&waitTimeSeconds=20&maxMessagesPerPoll=10&visibilityTimeout=30&deleteAfterRead=true")
.to("seda:inbound-queue?waitForTaskToComplete=Never&concurrentConsumers=1")
.process(new MyProcessor());
```

IF I delete the SEDA route statement, it works as expected

```
from("aws-sqs://myqueue?amazonSQSClient=#myclientbean&waitTimeSeconds=20&maxMessagesPerPoll=10&visibilityTimeout=30&deleteAfterRead=true")
// COMMENT OUT AND SQS messages get deleted 
// .to("seda:inbound-queue?waitForTaskToComplete=Never&concurrentConsumers=1")
.process(new MyProcessor());
```

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9055

Comment: I face a similar issue, but I get this error: CAMEL: 2.18.3

org.apache.camel.component.aws.sqs.SqsConsumer  - Error occurred during deleting message. This exception is ignored..Caused by: [com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException - The request must contain the parameter MessageHandle. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MissingParameter; 
com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: The request must contain the parameter MessageHandle. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: MissingParameter;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears to be fixed with this issue at apache:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-9055